# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable при выводе данных массива на экран

Tags: python, массивы, классы, list

пишу рогалик на питоне. При выводе уровня выходит ошибка TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. 
Сам код:

```
class object:
    stone=[" ","stone",True]
class start:
    def welcome():
        print("Welcome to python rogue-like")
    def generate():
        map = []
        m=[]
        for i in range(1, 20):
            m.append(object.stone)
        print(m)
        input()
        for b in range(0,19):
            map.append([m])
        return map
class output:
    def render(map):
        for af in range(0,len(map)):
            for it in range(0,len(map[af])):
                input(map)
                print(map[af[it[0]]])
class main_loop():
    start.welcome()
    output.render(start.generate())
    input()
```

Comment: map[af[it[0]]] тут ты пытаешься взять 0 элемент у it, хотя it это integer. Аналогично для af.

Comment: @Alpensin спасибо огромное! Еще не разобрался в синтаксисе двухмерных списков.